# jQuery toggle nested inside trigger not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason, the below simple script won't work - I want the sub-menu to toggle when I click on the "Portfolio" link (the sub-menu hides correctly).

If I change the trigger div so that it's elsewhere on the page, it works fine. Can someone explain what the problem with the below is? Are you not allowed to nest or something?

JS:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('.sub-menu').hide();
  $('#menu-item-154 > a').click(function(){
    $('.sub-menu').toggle();
  });
});
</script>
```

Page HTML

```
<div class="menu-main-menu-container">
  <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="">
    <li id="menu-item-154" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-154">
      <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-26" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-26"><a href="/?page_id=20">ITEM 1</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-55" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-55"><a href="/?page_id=48">ITEM 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    <li id="menu-item-56" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-56"><a href="/?cat=1">NEWS &#038; BLOG</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: [Seems to work alright for me](http://jsfiddle.net/sUBWd/3/) ? - Edit: There was an unclosed `<li>` in that html. I've corrected the html in that fiddle so it nests properly. That was probably your issue.

Comment: Looks like you've fixed your html now. You still having the issue? Double check jQuery is being loaded. Also is your menu being added to the page after the DOM has loaded?

Comment: @Adam The incorrect HTML doesn't seem to have caused a problem in the original jsFiddle anyway.

Comment: Yeah you're right, wasn't sure if jsfiddle / my browser was doing anything clever auto-closing open tags. Surprised it worked properly though lol. Just narrowing down what the issue could me, hence not actually posting an answer.

Comment: Thanks both for your help - my code works in the JS Fiddle. jQuery is definitely being loaded but I think the menu might be added to the page after the DOM is loaded, yes (it's a sliding effect) - is that a problem? Perhaps that's the issue? What's the best way to specify that this should be loaded last? My current script is in the header, but I can see a lot of JS is loaded at the bottom of the page...

Comment: It's possible that you are trying to bind an event to an object that doesn't exist yet. Don't worry though it is easily fixed with `on()`. [Here's a jsfiddle which should help explain it](http://jsfiddle.net/sUBWd/4/)

Comment: Adam - thanks so much, that code worked (I actually omitted the append as the <a> was inserted by the Wordpress menu). Want to add it as an answer and I'll accept?

Comment: Nick, can you please re-delete the `<li>` ? So that this question makes sense for others, that might have made the same mistake

Comment: This is done - marking your answer correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't close the `li` after the portfolio:

```
<li id="menu-item-154" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-154">
  <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
</li>
```

Why don't use the clickevent on the `a href` ?

```
<a id="opensub1" href="#">Portfolio</a>
```

Comment: closing of `</li>` is there after `<ul>`.. check it out

Comment: There was an unclosed <li> in that html that the aouthor has corrected right away, so this should be marked as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

use `find()`

```
  $('.sub-menu').hide();
  $('#menu-item-154').find('a').click(function(){
    $('.sub-menu').toggle();
  });
```

Comment: Why use a function that gives them different (and, I would think, incorrect) functionality when there doesn't seem to actually be a problem with the code posted?